# Is there a way to name a foreign key in golang's gorm db

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have two tables named `chapter_reward_resource_attribute_values` and `chapter_reward_resources` and a `belongs-to` foreign key constraint between the two

```
type ChapterRewardResource struct { ... }
type ChapterRewardResourceAttributeValue struct {
  ChapterRewardResource   ChapterRewardResource
  ChapterRewardResourceID uint
  ...
}
```

`go-gorm` was supposed to auto create a foreign key named `fk_chapter_reward_resource_attribute_values_chapter_reward_resource` but the name length exceeds 64 characters -- which is a hard limit of MySQL -- so the creation failed with error:

```
2021/07/17 00:50:21 /data/github/test-comlibs/models/migrate.go:148 Error 1300: Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'fkchapter_reward_resource_attribute_valueschapter_reward\xDE\...'
[0.119ms] [rows:0] ALTER TABLE `chapter_reward_resource_attribute_values` ADD CONSTRAINT `fkchapter_reward_resource_attribute_valueschapter_reward<DE>^C<8B><92><9D>^XͿ` FOREIGN KEY (`chapter_reward_resource_id`) REFERENCES `chapter_reward_resources`(`id`)
```

I tried with shorter names for the tables and saw the success of the creation. However, I would like to keep the names unchanged for consistency. Is there a way that I can manually specify name for a foreign key constraint?

Comment: First of all error says something else `Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'fkchapter_reward_resource_attribute_valueschapter_reward\xDE\...'`, means you are using `utf8mb4` character in column or table name.

Comment: @Eklavya Yep, but thing is that go-gorm somehow generates the wrong name `fkchapter_reward_resource_attribute_valueschapter_reward<DE>^C<8B><92><9D>^XͿ` as the supposed-to-be name exceeds 64 characters -- this is something like buffer overflow in go-gorm I would assume.

Comment: A possible way can be disable foreign key generation and create by own with raw SQL and migrate. https://gorm.io/docs/constraints.html#Foreign-Key-Constraint

Comment: And you can shorten the table name using `TableName()` https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#TableName

Comment: @Eklavya Thank you for your hint. I found a thing called `RelationshipFKName(Relationship) string` at https://gorm.io/docs/gorm_config.html#NamingStrategy but couldn't find a start-up example. Have you ever tried this? Do you know how to get started with it?

Comment: Here is the default implementation which will help you to write. You can just override with your own implementation https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/50e85e14d4510a66505b19f50d6e29508fbd96e6/schema/naming.go#L62